# I have a plumbing issue with dripping shower

Tags: plumbing

I turned off the water at the main when I turned it on I noticed a constant drip from the shower when it is off

How can I stop the drip and balance the water through out my house

Comment: Your shower has a leak.  Will need to fix the leak.  Water is already balanced.

Comment: This is stating the obvious, but did you try turning the shower on and the back off again?  Sometimes that fixes it, sometimes not.

Comment: open the shower and release the air pressure

Comment: What does "balance the water" mean? What would you be attempting to achieve by doing that?

Answer (score 1):

This is frustrating to deal with! Luckily, it's usually an easy fix.

Most likely, you have a bad valve. This is something you can do yourself, or have an experienced friend take care of. Not something you need to call a professional plumber for (although you can if you'd like the warranty of their work)

Here is an article that goes into more detail about it and it even offers a how to guide if you want to tackle this project yourself.
https://www.hgtv.com/content/hgtv-com/en/how-to/home-improvement/articles/2020/how-to-fix-a-leaky-shower-head.html

Just in case, here is another place you could look:
https://www.homedepot.com/c/ah/how-to-fix-a-leaky-shower-faucet/9ba683603be9fa5395fab9016cbb4f8c

Be sure to turn off the water supply before you do anything. Also, depending on your style of shower, you will need a screwdriver and/or hex tool and a wrench.

-Once the water is off, remove the handle cap, handle, and faceplate.

-If your shower has one, remove the locking clip (Not all showers have this).

-Remove and replace the cartidge/valve

You could also take this opportunity to replace other shower parts that have suffered wear and tear. Even though they may still work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As with _every_ SE site, this is, essentially, a link-only answer and is useless when HGTV rearranges their site. Please edit to include relevant bits from the link.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).